# Setting a date based on days away and day of the week?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to set a date to be at least 14 days away on a Wednesday.  Meaning if the date is 3/14/16 it would set it to be 3/30/16.  If it is 3/10 it would be 3/30 also.  Looking to use ruby.

So my thought is something like this:

```
def next_weds
  self + (14 + closest_wed_day)
end
```

The issue is how to define wedday meaning, how do I get the closest Wednesday and then add 14 to that date.   So if today is Tuesday it would be adding 15.  If it is Thursday it would add 20.

Comment: What have you tried? We will be happy to help you debug your code, but we are not here to write it for you...

Comment: Just added what I have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/mojombo/chronic/ does this easily. Here's your example:

```
Chronic.parse('14 days from now wednesday')
=> 2016-04-20 00:00:00 -0500
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pure-Ruby solution.

```
require 'date'

def first_day_of_week(min_days_from_now, day_of_week)
  today = Date.today
  days_until_day_of_week = (7 + day_of_week - today.wday) % 7
  today + days_until_day_of_week +
    7*(([min_days_from_now-days_until_day_of_week, 0].max/7.0).ceil)
end
```

Today is:

```
today = Date.today
  #=> #<Date: 2016-03-31 ((2457479j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)> 
wday = today.wday
  #=> 4 
Date::DAYNAMES[wday]
  #=> "Thursday"
```

Suppose:

```
day_of_week = 3
Date::DAYNAMES[day_of_week]
  #=> "Wednesday"
```

Then:

```
puts "      # min_days_from_now   date     wday"
(0..14).each do |min_days_from_now|
  fd = first_day_of_week(min_days_from_now, day_of_week)
  puts "      #        %2d        %s   %d" % [min_days_from_now, fd.to_s, fd.wday]
end
  # min_days_from_now   date     wday
  #         0        2016-04-06   3
  #         1        2016-04-06   3
  #         2        2016-04-06   3
  #         3        2016-04-06   3
  #         4        2016-04-06   3
  #         5        2016-04-06   3
  #         6        2016-04-06   3
  #         7        2016-04-13   3
  #         8        2016-04-13   3
  #         9        2016-04-13   3
  #        10        2016-04-13   3
  #        11        2016-04-13   3
  #        12        2016-04-13   3
  #        13        2016-04-13   3
  #        14        2016-04-20   3
```